# How important is feature selection for Light Gradient Boosting Machine?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, boosting

My understanding is that LGBM will, more or less, figure out on its own which features are important and which not

Does it still make any sense to do any feature selection before training a LGBM model?

Comment: You're correct that "LGBM will, more or less, figure out on its own which features are important and which [are] not." Can you be more specific about what additional problem you're trying to solve by doing feature selection prior to estimating the gradient-boosted model?

Comment: @Sycorax Basically, I am looking into ways to improve the performance of a LGBM regression model and I am not sure whether I should spend time on doing a feature selection prior to training the model

Comment: Any model will benefit, if you are somehow magically able to provide it only those features that have predictive value and ideally transformed in such a way that it helps the particular model the most. Many variable selection methods that get used are not really good at doing that though.

Comment: The internal feature selection of gradient-boosted trees is selecting the best splits during tree construction. This is often enough. If you have an enormous number of non-informative features, then one might find that searching these non-informative features is a waste of time. But adding a feature selection step is not free: it takes time to find the informative features, and any method carries the risk that it makes a mistake (includes an irrelevant feature, excludes a relevant feature). I don't think there's an answer to this question that's independent of the specific usage.